# Text with variable in one line [HTML JS] (and the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything)

Tags: javascript, html

The program works correctly so far. But I want the solution to be answered in one line.
So that's what I programmed so far:

```html
    <h3>Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything</h3>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
    <p>The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything is:
    <p id="wert">not answered
    <p>, nice!
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = 42;
    document.getElementById("wert").innerHTML = x;
    }
    </script>
```

**Thank you, I appreciate your help!**

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an [inline](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) element, like a `<span>`

```html
<h3>Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything</h3>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">calculate</button>
    <p>The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything is:
    <span id="wert">not answered
    </span>
    </p>, nice!
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = 42;
    document.getElementById("wert").innerHTML = x;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: you could also change the `display` property of a `div` or `p` element, i suppose. did you want the "not answered" to be in the same line as well?

Comment: you could also just add 42 to the existing element, like `.innerHTML+="42"`` on the p element